# Automatically insert new record into association when using has_one or has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Right now I have two tables, users and roles, of course roles has a user_id and the roles model has `belongs_to :user` and the user model has `has_one :role`.  The question I'm wondering is, how do I have the User model create the new record in the Role model.  I understand I can do this outside of the model just as easily as I create the user, but I figure it might be more streamlined and keep everything in one spot and simplify it if I do it in the User model.  Are there any suggestions on how I could easily do this without knowing the id of the user before it's saved?

Note: (I would only allow this when new_record? is true, otherwise it will be forbidden.)

Comment: if the user only has one role, why use a seperate table for roles, instead of just adding a role column to the User model through a migration?

Comment: @entropy_9 I think you confuse the association created by 'has_one' perhaps? Just because a user has_one row in the roles table doesn't mean they only have one absolute role.  Yes people prefer to use has_many I assume (I've seen is used plenty of times for this) but what is the point when there is a one to one association of roles and users on the rows in the tables? That just creates inefficiency IMO unless I misunderstand the docs.

Comment: ah, ok I must have misinterpreted the OP. In similar problems I've had in the past I just added a 'role' field to the User table, specifying a default role (e.g user/guest) in the migration, so I leaned on that in my original comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing something similar with user & their settings, probably this could work for you:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

#...

has_one :role
before_create :build_a_role

private
  def build_a_role
    self.build_role(role_att: value)
  end
end
```

Then, when the user is saved, the role is saved too.